# Central Limit Theorem applicable for for weighted summation of random variables?

Tags: statistics

If $X_1, X_2, X_3, \ldots, X_{20}$ are twenty random variables (independent /  i.i.d.)

> What would be the result of $ \displaystyle 2X_1+ 5X_2 + X_3 + 18X_4 \ldots + \frac12 X_{20}$? (linear combination of the random variables, with fixed known constants).

Will the above function have a normal probability distribution if we take say $100000$ instances of the values of $[X_1,X_2, \ldots X_{20}]$. And will the normal distribution be tighter (smaller variance) if we take $30$ instead of $2$0 random variables?

Does it have to do with Central Limit Theorem? Because I thought CLT was only for arithmetic mean of random variables and not for linear combination (weighted summation/ scaled summation)?

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: If you are looking at the mean of an increasing number of samples of the weighted sum then you will see Central Limit Theorem effects (assuming that the sum has a finite variance).  But if you simply add on more weighted random variables to the sum then the variance of the sum will increase rather than reduce.

Comment: I forgot to mention that each random variable xi is positive and sum of all xi is always 1. Sorry, it was an important thing to be missed..! Please let me know your view now.

Comment: If the sum is always $1$ then they are not independent

Comment: In that case, how do we call them, because I thought they are random variables within these constraints. Also, what would be the result of a linear combination of Xis? Will it still have a normal distribution with tighter distribution as sample size increases (like CLT). My understanding was CLT only said this about arithmetic mean of Xi's, not about linear combinations. Please let me know. Thanks.